# Как привязать размер иконки в диалоге к ширине экрана?

Tags: java, android, icon

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.setTitle("ВЫХОД из программы");
dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tt128);
dialog.setMessage("Уже уходите ?!");
```

Иконка "tt128.png" имеет размер: 128х128.

Иконка на разных экранах имеет разный размер (с маленьким разрешением: слишком большая, с большим разрешением: слишком маленькая).

Ширина (dW) и высота (dH) экрана, с которого запускают приложение, известны. Как установить размеры иконки вышеописанного диалога в зависимости от dW и dH ?!

Решение: сделать много иконок для разных экранов - не предлагать)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - предварительно отресайзить битмап в нужный вам размер - [пример](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/).

Также можно использовать `android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`

Другой вариант - насколько я помню, у `Dialog` можно сделать `setView()`, указав нужный вам `layout` (например, считать его из ресурсов), тем самым полностью заменить содержимое диалога, в том числе `message` и `icon`.
Ну а уж в своем `layout` можно наворопупить всего чего угодно, в том числе `icon` нужного размера.

Answer (score 1):

Все получилось!

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/homecolor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
package com.images;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static int sW;
    private int sH;
    public static Float dens;
    public static int newW;
    public Bitmap im;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        int height = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        int width = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        dens = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        sW = width; sH = height;
        newW = sW/2; // вывод изображения в половину ширины экрана

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.homecolor), newW, newW));
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
}
```

[image: Тестовая картинка]

В результате картинка выводится на всех экранах в половину ширины экрана (что и требовалось)!